# How do you wait for a drive to load before running a startup script on Windows 10?

Tags: windows-10, external-hard-drive, script

I have a program in an external drive, and I want to run it at startup, but putting it in the startup folder causes a file not found issue, because the drive had yet to be online. Is there a way to wait for the device to be accessible before accessing it?

Comment: You did not give us many details. You can simply put a script with a delay first and then load the script from the extrnal drive.

Comment: What details are missing?

Comment: Also, the drive may not be connected for some time, so I can't just pick some arbitrary delay.

Comment: Well what kind of scripting lang. are you using? Why you need it the reasoning behind it. You dont need a fixed delay, you can wait till the it appears in the drive list...

Comment: A windows batch file would be run at startup

Comment: I want to run a program on a drive automatically so I do not have to manually run it every time the system boots.

Comment: Ok, why you have it on external drive then?

Comment: It is a third party program and can only be run from the drive

Comment: The script can be placed in different place than the program.

Comment: I know, and that is the problem because, the script is run at startup, before the OS puts the drive online.

Answer (score 0):

If it were me, I would start with a script using AutoIT.
https://www.autoitscript.com/site/autoit/downloads/

Compile it to an EXE, have it run at windows bootup by putting it in RUN section of Windows registry. Have it check for the existence of a particular file in the root of the external drive.
If it doesn't find it, retry it every 10 seconds.  Have option to give up after xx minutes and exit the script.
When it finds it, have it run your app , then  exit the script.

Somewhat steep learning curve but it includes lots of samples in the installer, plus their website.

Comment: What's wrong with running a batch file with the task scheduler?

Comment: @JohnGlen, but in task scheduler you can set 'if task fails try every .. minutes', no?